# Set click event to every <a> inside a <li> element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been reading some posts about it but I don't get it to work, I don't know why, the idea is, when clicks on  inside a my list menu it shows the span of this .

```
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav side-nav">
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-arrow-circle-o-right fa-2x"></i> Inicio</a>
                </li>
                 <li>
                    <a href="RegistrarEspecialista.php" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demoF">Especialistas</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demoCC">Pacientes<i class="fa fa-fw fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                    <ul id="demoCC" class="collapse">
                            <li>
                                <a href="RegistrarPaciente.php">Registro</a>
                            </li>


                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">Citas<i class="fa fa-fw fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                    <ul id="demo" class="collapse">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Registro</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                               <a href="#">Consultas</a>
                            </li>                            
                    </ul>
                </li> 
            </ul>
```

there is the html, and It is my script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul.nav navbar-nav side-nav li a').click(function(e){ 
         alert($(this).find("span.t").text());
         e.preventDefault();
    });
 });
```

Comment: did you try $('ul.nav li a').click(...) instead?

Comment: I don't see any `<span>` elements in your HTML. What are you trying to select?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works fine:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.nav li a').click(function(e){ 
         e.preventDefault();
        alert($(this).find("span.t").text());

    });
 });
```

But like `showdev` mentioned you will have an empty alert as there is no `<span>` element inside your html.

I suggest you FIRST `preventDefault()` than do other actions, it's the correct sequence.

Answer (score 2):

Your initial selector:

```
$('ul.nav navbar-nav side-nav li a')
```

Is malformed. That would be saying find all `navbar-nav` elements with child `side-nav` elements with `li a` elements, within a parent `ul.nav`. But `navbar-nav` and `side-nav` are classes. And, even then, your `ul` has all three classes, so you'd need to chain them:

```
$('ul.nav.navbar-nav.side-nav li a')
```

Even then, that's probably way more specific a selector than is necessary. I'm guessing that `.side-nav` is the most explicit. And then it's not even necessary to declare the tag name (over specifying can be problematic). So perhaps simply this would be best:

```
$('.side-nav li a').on('click', function(e) {
  // handler code
});
```